# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, nginx

Can anybody help me with my nginx configuration, it's driving me nuts.

I've made so many changes to my sites-available and sites-enabled and my nginx.conf file that i'm not sure what's up or down anymore. I change from 404 errors to 502 errors. I've changed permissions on folders and changed ports that it listens to.

```
    server {
    listen      80;

    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;
    root        /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    #location /app/                       { deny all; }
    #location /includes/                  { deny all; }
    #location /lib/                       { deny all; }
    #location /media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
    #location /pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
    #location /report/config.xml          { deny all; }
    #location /var/                       { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
        autoindex               on;
    }
    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }
    gzip on;
    #gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml text/css text/js application/x-javascript;
}
```

nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

     server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

If i tail -f my access log:

```
52.25.122.161 - - [12/Feb/2017:00:20:36 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
66.249.64.68 - - [12/Feb/2017:00:36:15 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.64.68 - - [12/Feb/2017:01:47:53 -0700] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
27.105.104.2 - - [12/Feb/2017:02:55:17 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
139.162.108.53 - - [12/Feb/2017:06:03:19 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
86.111.145.222 - - [12/Feb/2017:06:46:19 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "curl/7.17.1 (mips-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.17.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8i zlib/1.2.3"
89.248.163.3 - - [12/Feb/2017:07:53:05 -0700] "GET /muieblackcat HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "-"
89.248.163.3 - - [12/Feb/2017:07:53:05 -0700] "GET //pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "-" "-"
89.248.163.3 - - [12/Feb/2017:07:53:05 -0700] "GET //phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1" 404 178 "-" "-"
54.169.31.205 - - [12/Feb/2017:08:47:01 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 182 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 GTB6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
```

Comment: Can you post your access logs?

Comment: Do you have a `php-fpm` process listening on port 9000?

Comment: @FaisalMemon, i posted my access log.

Comment: @Richard Smith, I'm not sure what port my php-fpm is listening on? I'll check now.

Comment: `sockstat` should tell you if a process is listening on port 9000 (I suspect it may not be). Also, you should look at the error log also.